# specify time interval in ssrs

Tags: performance, reporting-services, filter, report

Please help with performance and also making the report take the time interval into consideration
I am working on a SSRS report with filters, but it seems like my time interval filter isn’t working at all and the report performance is dead crazy (over 5 minutes). It got crazier with the addition of the time interval filter.
In order to get the 24 possible hour interval, which feeds the Interval menu, I created this stored procedure, which I call from the report just for the Interval drop down filter menu:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Calls_Time_Interval] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@TZ INT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT Distinct      

--CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) AS Time,

Case 
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '00:00:00.0000000' and '00:59:59.0000000' Then '00:00-01:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '01:00:00.0000000' and '01:59:59.0000000' Then '01:00-02:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '02:00:00.0000000' and '02:59:59.0000000' Then '02:00-03:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '03:00:00.0000000' and '03:59:59.0000000' Then '03:00-04:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '04:00:00.0000000' and '04:59:59.0000000' Then '04:00-05:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '05:00:00.0000000' and '05:59:59.0000000' Then '05:00-06:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '06:00:00.0000000' and '06:59:59.0000000' Then '06:00-07:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '07:00:00.0000000' and '07:59:59.0000000' Then '07:00-08:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '08:00:00.0000000' and '08:59:59.0000000' Then '08:00-09:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '09:00:00.0000000' and '09:59:59.0000000' Then '09:00-10:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '10:00:00.0000000' and '10:59:59.0000000' Then '10:00-11:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '11:00:00.0000000' and '11:59:59.0000000' Then '11:00-12:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '12:00:00.0000000' and '12:59:59.0000000' Then '12:00-13:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '13:00:00.0000000' and '13:59:59.0000000' Then '13:00-14:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '14:00:00.0000000' and '14:59:59.0000000' Then '14:00-15:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '15:00:00.0000000' and '15:59:59.0000000' Then '15:00-16:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '16:00:00.0000000' and '16:59:59.0000000' Then '16:00-17:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '17:00:00.0000000' and '17:59:59.0000000' Then '17:00-18:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '18:00:00.0000000' and '18:59:59.0000000' Then '18:00-19:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '19:00:00.0000000' and '19:59:59.0000000' Then '19:00-20:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '20:00:00.0000000' and '20:59:59.0000000' Then '20:00-21:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '21:00:00.0000000' and '21:59:59.0000000' Then '21:00-22:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '22:00:00.0000000' and '22:59:59.0000000' Then '22:00-23:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '23:00:00.0000000' and '23:59:59.0000000' Then '23:00-00:00'
              Else 'To be Determined' End As Interval 

FROM            CA_Details_Sync
WHERE        (disposition = 2 OR (disposition = 3 and callpriority <> 0)) AND ((dispskill = 702 AND dispvector = 1022) 
OR(dispskill = 701 AND dispvector = 1021) 
OR(dispskill = 924 AND dispvector = 1007) OR(dispskill = 923 AND dispvector = 1006) OR(dispskill = 611 AND dispvector = 1001) OR (dispskill = 613 AND dispvector = 1003) 
OR (dispskill = 614 AND dispvector = 1004)
    OR (dispskill IN (631) AND dispvector = 1009) OR (dispskill IN (616, 900) AND dispvector = 1006) OR (dispskill = 631 AND dispvector = 202) 
    OR (dispskill IN (617, 618, 901) AND dispvector = 1007)) AND (enddate < convert(date, getutcdate()))

GROUP BY CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime))
END

GO
```

The main report Dataset calls another stored procedure which I created as such:

```
USE [SPReports]
GO

  /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_GSC_Calls_Skills]    Script Date: 9/29/2015 1:01:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GSC_Calls_Skills] 

-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@YEAR NVARCHAR(255),
@MONTH NVARCHAR(255),

@SKILL NVARCHAR(255),

@TZ INT,
@Interval NVARCHAR(255)


AS
BEGIN

(SELECT     YEAR(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) AS Year, 
                MONTH(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) AS Month, 
                COUNT(cads_id) AS Calls, 
                SUM(CASE [disposition] WHEN 2 THEN CAST(ringtime+queuetime AS float) / 86400 ELSE 0 END) AS answertimetf, 
                SUM(CASE [disposition] WHEN 2 THEN CAST(talktime AS float) / 86400 ELSE 0 END) AS durationtf,
                CASE 

                    WHEN dispskill  IN ('611', '614') THEN 'GTK-English' 
                    WHEN dispskill = '613' THEN 'GTK-Spanish' 
                    WHEN dispskill IN ('616', '900', '631') THEN 'GTK-HSIA/GNOC' 
                    WHEN dispskill IN ('617') THEN 'GTK-FTG'
                    WHEN dispskill IN ('618', '901') THEN 'GTK-VOD/ETVI' 
                    WHEN dispskill  IN ('923') THEN 'SNS-HSIA'
                    WHEN dispskill  IN ('924') THEN 'SNS-VOC' 
                    WHEN dispskill  IN ('701') THEN 'T2-HSIA' 
                    WHEN dispskill  IN ('702') THEN 'T2-VOC' 
                    ELSE cast(dispskill as nvarchar(3)) + '-' + dispskillname END AS SkillSet, 
                CASE 
                    WHEN dispskill  IN ('611', '614') THEN 3
                    WHEN dispskill = '613' THEN 4 
                    WHEN dispskill IN ('616', '900', '631') THEN 5 
                    WHEN dispskill IN ('617') THEN 6 
                    WHEN dispskill IN ('618', '901') THEN 7
                    WHEN dispskill IN ('923') THEN 8 
                    WHEN dispskill IN ('924') THEN 9 
                    WHEN dispskill IN ('701') THEN 10 
                    WHEN dispskill IN ('702') THEN 11 
                    ELSE 0 END AS SkillSetPos,
                DAY(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) AS Day, 
                SUM(CASE disposition WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Answered, 
                SUM(CASE disposition WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Abandoned, Case 
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '00:00:00.0000000' and '00:59:59.0000000' Then '00:00-01:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '01:00:00.0000000' and '01:59:59.0000000' Then '01:00-02:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '02:00:00.0000000' and '02:59:59.0000000' Then '02:00-03:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '03:00:00.0000000' and '03:59:59.0000000' Then '03:00-04:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '04:00:00.0000000' and '04:59:59.0000000' Then '04:00-05:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '05:00:00.0000000' and '05:59:59.0000000' Then '05:00-06:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '06:00:00.0000000' and '06:59:59.0000000' Then '06:00-07:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '07:00:00.0000000' and '07:59:59.0000000' Then '07:00-08:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '08:00:00.0000000' and '08:59:59.0000000' Then '08:00-09:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '09:00:00.0000000' and '09:59:59.0000000' Then '09:00-10:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '10:00:00.0000000' and '10:59:59.0000000' Then '10:00-11:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '11:00:00.0000000' and '11:59:59.0000000' Then '11:00-12:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '12:00:00.0000000' and '12:59:59.0000000' Then '12:00-13:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '13:00:00.0000000' and '13:59:59.0000000' Then '13:00-14:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '14:00:00.0000000' and '14:59:59.0000000' Then '14:00-15:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '15:00:00.0000000' and '15:59:59.0000000' Then '15:00-16:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '16:00:00.0000000' and '16:59:59.0000000' Then '16:00-17:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '17:00:00.0000000' and '17:59:59.0000000' Then '17:00-18:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '18:00:00.0000000' and '18:59:59.0000000' Then '18:00-19:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '19:00:00.0000000' and '19:59:59.0000000' Then '19:00-20:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '20:00:00.0000000' and '20:59:59.0000000' Then '20:00-21:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '21:00:00.0000000' and '21:59:59.0000000' Then '21:00-22:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '22:00:00.0000000' and '22:59:59.0000000' Then '22:00-23:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '23:00:00.0000000' and '23:59:59.0000000' Then '23:00-00:00'
                  Else 'To be Determined' End As Interval 
FROM            CA_Details_Sync
WHERE        (disposition = 2 OR (disposition = 3 and callpriority <> 0)) AND ((dispskill = 702 AND dispvector = 1022) 
OR(dispskill = 701 AND dispvector = 1021) 
OR(dispskill = 924 AND dispvector = 1007) OR(dispskill = 923 AND dispvector = 1006) OR(dispskill = 611 AND dispvector = 1001) OR (dispskill = 613 AND dispvector = 1003) 
OR (dispskill = 614 AND dispvector = 1004)
    OR (dispskill IN (631) AND dispvector = 1009) OR (dispskill IN (616, 900) AND dispvector = 1006) OR (dispskill = 631 AND dispvector = 202) 
    OR (dispskill IN (617, 618, 901) AND dispvector = 1007)) AND (enddate < convert(date, getutcdate()))

GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)), 
        MONTH(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)), 
        CASE 
            WHEN dispskill  IN ('611', '614') THEN 'GTK-English' 
            WHEN dispskill = '613' THEN 'GTK-Spanish' 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('616', '900', '631') THEN 'GTK-HSIA/GNOC'
            WHEN dispskill IN ('617') THEN 'GTK-FTG' 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('618', '901') THEN 'GTK-VOD/ETVI' 
            WHEN dispskill= '923' THEN 'SNS-HSIA' 
            WHEN dispskill='924' THEN 'SNS-VOC' 
            WHEN dispskill='701' THEN 'T2-HSIA' 
            WHEN dispskill  IN ('702') THEN 'T2-VOC' 
            ELSE cast(dispskill as nvarchar(3)) + '-' + dispskillname END,
            DAY(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)), 
            CASE 
            WHEN dispskill  IN ('611', '614') THEN 3 
            WHEN dispskill = '613' THEN 4 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('616', '900', '631') THEN 5 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('617') THEN 6 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('618', '901') THEN 7
            WHEN dispskill IN ('923') THEN 8 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('924') THEN 9 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('701') THEN 10 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('702') THEN 11 
            ELSE 0 END,
            CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime))

HAVING        (YEAR(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) IN
                             (SELECT        Value
                               FROM            dbo.FnSplit(@Year, ',') AS FnSplit_2)) AND 
            (MONTH(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) IN
                             (SELECT        Value
                               FROM            dbo.FnSplit(@Month, ',') AS FnSplit_1))
                               AND 
            (CASE WHEN dispskill  IN ('611', '614') THEN 'GTK-English' 
            WHEN dispskill = '613' THEN 'GTK-Spanish' 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('616', '900', '631') THEN 'GTK-HSIA/GNOC'
            WHEN dispskill IN ('617') THEN 'GTK-FTG' 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('618', '901') THEN 'GTK-VOD/ETVI' 
            WHEN dispskill= '923' THEN 'SNS-HSIA' 
            WHEN dispskill='924' THEN 'SNS-VOC' 
            WHEN dispskill='701' THEN 'T2-HSIA' 
            WHEN dispskill  IN ('702') THEN 'T2-VOC' 
            ELSE cast(dispskill as nvarchar(3)) + '-' + dispskillname END IN
                             (SELECT        Value
                               FROM            dbo.FnSplit(@Skill, ',') AS FnSplit_3)))
UNION
(SELECT       YEAR(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, [Enter Queue]))) + CONVERT(time, [Enter Queue])) AS Year, 
              MONTH(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, [Enter Queue]))) + CONVERT(time, [Enter Queue])) AS Month, 
              COUNT(id) AS Calls, 
             Sum(CASE WHEN Status IN ('COMPLETE', 'TRANSFER') THEN CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, [Queue Wait])*60+DATEPART(SECOND, [Queue Wait]) AS float) / 86400 ELSE 0 END) AS ringtimetf, 
              Sum(CASE WHEN status IN ('COMPLETE', 'TRANSFER') THEN CAST(duration1 AS float) / 86400 ELSE 0 END) AS durationtf, 
              CASE WHEN [Application] IN ('GTK - English','GTK - English Extended Stay','GTK - English Four Seasons','GTK - English GPNS','GTK - English Hilton','GTK - English Marriot',
                                         'GTK - English WCH', 'GTK - LaQuinta', 'gtkEN', 'gtkENfourSeasons', 'gtkENgpns', 'gtkENLaQuinta', 'gtkENMarriot') THEN 'Conectys English' 
                   WHEN [Application] IN ('gtkFR', 'gtkFRgpns', 'gtkFRMarriot') THEN 'Conectys French' END AS SkillSet, 
              CASE WHEN [Application] IN ('GTK - English', 'GTK - English Extended Stay', 'GTK - English Four Seasons', 'GTK - English GPNS', 'GTK - English Hilton', 'GTK - English Marriot',
                                          'GTK - English WCH', 'GTK - LaQuinta', 'gtkEN', 'gtkENfourSeasons', 'gtkENgpns', 'gtkENLaQuinta', 'gtkENMarriot') THEN 1 
                WHEN [Application] IN ('gtkFR', 'gtkFRgpns', 'gtkFRMarriot') THEN 2 END AS SkillSetPos,
              DAY(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, [Enter Queue]))) + CONVERT(time, [Enter Queue])) AS Day, 
              SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ('COMPLETE', 'TRANSFER') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Answered,
              SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ('LOST', 'TIME OUT') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Abandoned, Case 
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '00:00:00.0000000' and '00:59:59.0000000' Then '00:00-01:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '01:00:00.0000000' and '01:59:59.0000000' Then '01:00-02:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '02:00:00.0000000' and '02:59:59.0000000' Then '02:00-03:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '03:00:00.0000000' and '03:59:59.0000000' Then '03:00-04:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '04:00:00.0000000' and '04:59:59.0000000' Then '04:00-05:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '05:00:00.0000000' and '05:59:59.0000000' Then '05:00-06:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '06:00:00.0000000' and '06:59:59.0000000' Then '06:00-07:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '07:00:00.0000000' and '07:59:59.0000000' Then '07:00-08:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '08:00:00.0000000' and '08:59:59.0000000' Then '08:00-09:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '09:00:00.0000000' and '09:59:59.0000000' Then '09:00-10:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '10:00:00.0000000' and '10:59:59.0000000' Then '10:00-11:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '11:00:00.0000000' and '11:59:59.0000000' Then '11:00-12:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '12:00:00.0000000' and '12:59:59.0000000' Then '12:00-13:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '13:00:00.0000000' and '13:59:59.0000000' Then '13:00-14:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '14:00:00.0000000' and '14:59:59.0000000' Then '14:00-15:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '15:00:00.0000000' and '15:59:59.0000000' Then '15:00-16:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '16:00:00.0000000' and '16:59:59.0000000' Then '16:00-17:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '17:00:00.0000000' and '17:59:59.0000000' Then '17:00-18:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '18:00:00.0000000' and '18:59:59.0000000' Then '18:00-19:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '19:00:00.0000000' and '19:59:59.0000000' Then '19:00-20:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '20:00:00.0000000' and '20:59:59.0000000' Then '20:00-21:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '21:00:00.0000000' and '21:59:59.0000000' Then '21:00-22:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '22:00:00.0000000' and '22:59:59.0000000' Then '22:00-23:00'
                  When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) between '23:00:00.0000000' and '23:59:59.0000000' Then '23:00-00:00'
                  Else 'To be Determined' End As Interval
FROM            Connectys_Calls
WHERE        (CONVERT(date, [Enter Queue]) < CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())) AND Status <> 'CUSTOMER EXIT' AND [Application] LIKE 'G%'
AND
        (YEAR(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, [Enter Queue]))) + CONVERT(time, [Enter Queue])) IN
                             (SELECT        Value
                               FROM            dbo.FnSplit(@Year, ',') AS FnSplit_2)) AND 
            (MONTH(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, [Enter Queue]))) + CONVERT(time, [Enter Queue])) IN
                             (SELECT        Value
                               FROM            dbo.FnSplit(@Month, ',') AS FnSplit_1))

GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, [Enter Queue]))) + CONVERT(time, [Enter Queue])), 
        MONTH(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, [Enter Queue]))) + CONVERT(time, [Enter Queue])), 
        DAY(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, [Enter Queue]))) + CONVERT(time, [Enter Queue])), 
        CASE WHEN [Application] IN ('GTK - English', 'GTK - English Extended Stay', 'GTK - English Four Seasons', 'GTK - English GPNS', 'GTK - English Hilton', 'GTK - English Marriot',
'GTK - English WCH', 'GTK - LaQuinta', 'gtkEN', 'gtkENfourSeasons', 'gtkENgpns', 'gtkENLaQuinta', 'gtkENMarriot') THEN 'Conectys English'               WHEN [Application] IN ('gtkFR',
'gtkFRgpns', 'gtkFRMarriot') THEN 'Conectys French' END, 
              CASE WHEN [Application] IN ('GTK - English', 'GTK - English Extended Stay','GTK - English Four Seasons','GTK - English GPNS','GTK - English Hilton','GTK - English Marriot',
'GTK - English WCH','GTK - LaQuinta','gtkEN','gtkENfourSeasons','gtkENgpns','gtkENLaQuinta','gtkENMarriot') THEN 1 
                WHEN [Application] IN ('gtkFR','gtkFRgpns',
'gtkFRMarriot') THEN 2 END ,CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue])))
HAVING       
            (CASE WHEN [Application] IN ('GTK - English', 'GTK - English Extended Stay','GTK - English Four Seasons','GTK - English GPNS','GTK - English Hilton','GTK - English Marriot',
'GTK - English WCH','GTK - LaQuinta','gtkEN','gtkENfourSeasons', 'gtkENgpns','gtkENLaQuinta','gtkENMarriot') THEN 'Conectys English'

WHEN [Application] IN ('gtkFR','gtkFRgpns','gtkFRMarriot') THEN 'Conectys French' END IN
                             (SELECT        Value
                               FROM            dbo.FnSplit(@Skill, ',') AS FnSplit_3)))

END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, your doing a lot of calculations over and over again - especially with your time interval.

I would make a subquery that adds a column with your time **interval** calculation:

```
....
SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ('COMPLETE', 'TRANSFER') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Answered,
SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ('LOST', 'TIME OUT') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Abandoned, 
RIGHT('00' + CAST(Hour_Interval AS VARCHAR(10)), 2) + ':00-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@HOURS + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)), 2) + ':00' AS INTERVAL
Else 'To be Determined' End As Interval
FROM (  SELECT * , DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, [Enter Queue]))) End As Hour_Interval
        FROM Connectys_Calls ) AS CC
....
```

For your time interval filter drop-down, is it really necessary to call the actual dataset? If you're going to have all values most of the time, just give all hour ranges:

```
DECLARE @HOURS AS INTEGER = 0

SELECT @HOURS AS HOURS, RIGHT('00' + CAST(@HOURS AS VARCHAR(10)), 2) + ':00-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@HOURS + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)), 2) + ':00' AS RANGES 
INTO #TEMP_HOURS

SET @HOURS = @HOURS + 1

WHILE @HOURS <24 

BEGIN 

INSERT INTO #TEMP_HOURS
SELECT @HOURS AS HOURS, RIGHT('00' + CAST(@HOURS AS VARCHAR(10)), 2) + ':00-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@HOURS + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)), 2) + ':00' AS RANGES

SET @HOURS = @HOURS + 1

END

SELECT * FROM #TEMP_HOURS
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The menu for time interval you suggested took less than a second to run. I am so grateful.  For the actual report though, i don't seem to understand how is that getting the time from the two tables. Consequently, it did not work. can you please provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

It takes a little less than 5 minutes to run this:

```
      Declare @YEAR NVARCHAR(255)
             Set @Year='2015'

       Declare @MONTH NVARCHAR(255)
       Set @Month='9'
       Declare @SKILL NVARCHAR(255)
       Set @Skill= 'GTK-English,Conectys English,Conectys French'
 --@SOURCE NVARCHAR(255),
Declare @TZ INT
Set @TZ=0
Declare @Interval NVARCHAR(255)
Set @Interval='06:00-07:00,07:00-08:00'
(SELECT     YEAR(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) AS Year, 
            MONTH(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) AS Month, 
            COUNT(cads_id) AS Calls, 
            SUM(CASE [disposition] WHEN 2 THEN CAST(ringtime+queuetime AS float) / 86400 ELSE 0 END) AS answertimetf, 
            SUM(CASE [disposition] WHEN 2 THEN CAST(talktime AS float) / 86400 ELSE 0 END) AS durationtf,
            CASE 

                WHEN dispskill  IN ('611', '614') THEN 'GTK-English' 
                WHEN dispskill = '613' THEN 'GTK-Spanish' 
                WHEN dispskill IN ('616', '900', '631') THEN 'GTK-HSIA/GNOC' 
                WHEN dispskill IN ('617') THEN 'GTK-FTG'
                WHEN dispskill IN ('618', '901') THEN 'GTK-VOD/ETVI' 
                WHEN dispskill  IN ('923') THEN 'SNS-HSIA'
                WHEN dispskill  IN ('924') THEN 'SNS-VOC' 
                WHEN dispskill  IN ('701') THEN 'T2-HSIA' 
                WHEN dispskill  IN ('702') THEN 'T2-VOC' 
                ELSE cast(dispskill as nvarchar(3)) + '-' + dispskillname END AS SkillSet, 
            CASE 
                WHEN dispskill  IN ('611', '614') THEN 3
                WHEN dispskill = '613' THEN 4 
                WHEN dispskill IN ('616', '900', '631') THEN 5 
                WHEN dispskill IN ('617') THEN 6 
                WHEN dispskill IN ('618', '901') THEN 7
                WHEN dispskill IN ('923') THEN 8 
                WHEN dispskill IN ('924') THEN 9 
                WHEN dispskill IN ('701') THEN 10 
                WHEN dispskill IN ('702') THEN 11 
                ELSE 0 END AS SkillSetPos,
            DAY(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) AS Day, 
            SUM(CASE disposition WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Answered, 
            SUM(CASE disposition WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Abandoned, Case 
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '00:00:00.0000000' and '00:59:59.0000000' Then '00:00-01:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '01:00:00.0000000' and '01:59:59.0000000' Then '01:00-02:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '02:00:00.0000000' and '02:59:59.0000000' Then '02:00-03:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '03:00:00.0000000' and '03:59:59.0000000' Then '03:00-04:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '04:00:00.0000000' and '04:59:59.0000000' Then '04:00-05:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '05:00:00.0000000' and '05:59:59.0000000' Then '05:00-06:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '06:00:00.0000000' and '06:59:59.0000000' Then '06:00-07:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '07:00:00.0000000' and '07:59:59.0000000' Then '07:00-08:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '08:00:00.0000000' and '08:59:59.0000000' Then '08:00-09:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '09:00:00.0000000' and '09:59:59.0000000' Then '09:00-10:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '10:00:00.0000000' and '10:59:59.0000000' Then '10:00-11:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '11:00:00.0000000' and '11:59:59.0000000' Then '11:00-12:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '12:00:00.0000000' and '12:59:59.0000000' Then '12:00-13:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '13:00:00.0000000' and '13:59:59.0000000' Then '13:00-14:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '14:00:00.0000000' and '14:59:59.0000000' Then '14:00-15:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '15:00:00.0000000' and '15:59:59.0000000' Then '15:00-16:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '16:00:00.0000000' and '16:59:59.0000000' Then '16:00-17:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '17:00:00.0000000' and '17:59:59.0000000' Then '17:00-18:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '18:00:00.0000000' and '18:59:59.0000000' Then '18:00-19:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '19:00:00.0000000' and '19:59:59.0000000' Then '19:00-20:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '20:00:00.0000000' and '20:59:59.0000000' Then '20:00-21:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '21:00:00.0000000' and '21:59:59.0000000' Then '21:00-22:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '22:00:00.0000000' and '22:59:59.0000000' Then '22:00-23:00'
              When CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) between '23:00:00.0000000' and '23:59:59.0000000' Then '23:00-00:00'
              Else 'To be Determined' End As Interval 
 FROM            CA_Details_Sync
WHERE        (disposition = 2 OR (disposition = 3 and callpriority <> 0))       AND ((dispskill = 702 AND dispvector = 1022) 
 OR(dispskill = 701 AND dispvector = 1021) 
 OR(dispskill = 924 AND dispvector = 1007) OR(dispskill = 923 AND dispvector   = 1006) OR(dispskill = 611 AND dispvector = 1001) OR (dispskill = 613 AND     dispvector = 1003) 
    OR (dispskill = 614 AND dispvector = 1004)
    OR (dispskill IN (631) AND dispvector = 1009) OR (dispskill IN (616,   900)    AND dispvector = 1006) OR (dispskill = 631 AND dispvector = 202) 
    OR (dispskill IN (617, 618, 901) AND dispvector = 1007)) AND (enddate <    convert(date, getutcdate()))

    GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)), 
    MONTH(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ),      CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)), 
           CASE 
            WHEN dispskill  IN ('611', '614') THEN 'GTK-English' 
          WHEN dispskill = '613' THEN 'GTK-Spanish' 
           WHEN dispskill IN ('616', '900', '631') THEN 'GTK-HSIA/GNOC'
           WHEN dispskill IN ('617') THEN 'GTK-FTG' 
           WHEN dispskill IN ('618', '901') THEN 'GTK-VOD/ETVI' 
           WHEN dispskill= '923' THEN 'SNS-HSIA' 
           WHEN dispskill='924' THEN 'SNS-VOC' 
          WHEN dispskill='701' THEN 'T2-HSIA' 
          WHEN dispskill  IN ('702') THEN 'T2-VOC' 
          ELSE cast(dispskill as nvarchar(3)) + '-' + dispskillname END,
          DAY(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) *   @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)), 
            CASE 
            WHEN dispskill  IN ('611', '614') THEN 3 
            WHEN dispskill = '613' THEN 4 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('616', '900', '631') THEN 5 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('617') THEN 6 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('618', '901') THEN 7
            WHEN dispskill IN ('923') THEN 8 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('924') THEN 9 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('701') THEN 10 
            WHEN dispskill IN ('702') THEN 11 
            ELSE 0 END,
            CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime))

HAVING        (YEAR(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) IN
                         (SELECT        Value
                           FROM            dbo.FnSplit(@Year, ',') AS FnSplit_2))    AND 
        (MONTH(DATEADD(HH, - (1 * DATEPART(HH, getutcdate() - GETDATE()) * @TZ), CONVERT(datetime, enddate)) + CONVERT(time, endtime)) IN
                          (SELECT        Value
                           FROM            dbo.FnSplit(@Month, ',') AS FnSplit_1))
                           AND 
          (CASE WHEN dispskill  IN ('611', '614') THEN 'GTK-English' 
        WHEN dispskill = '613' THEN 'GTK-Spanish' 
        WHEN dispskill IN ('616', '900', '631') THEN 'GTK-HSIA/GNOC'
        WHEN dispskill IN ('617') THEN 'GTK-FTG' 
        WHEN dispskill IN ('618', '901') THEN 'GTK-VOD/ETVI' 
        WHEN dispskill= '923' THEN 'SNS-HSIA' 
        WHEN dispskill='924' THEN 'SNS-VOC' 
        WHEN dispskill='701' THEN 'T2-HSIA' 
        WHEN dispskill  IN ('702') THEN 'T2-VOC' 
        ELSE cast(dispskill as nvarchar(3)) + '-' + dispskillname END IN
                         (SELECT        Value
                           FROM            dbo.FnSplit(@Skill, ',') AS FnSplit_3)))
```